# Meaning of どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか

Tags: meaning, translation

In a book I'm reading I found this sentence, which I'm not quite sure about:

> N先生、わたしは今日まで先生を尊敬もし、信頼もしてきました。こんな形でTheEndなんて何とも胸クソが悪い。
>
> **わざわざお母さんに、「教室移動の時間が長くなっている」と遠まわしに言わなくとも、ズバッと、わたしに向かって、「お前は東高じゃあ面倒みきれんで養護学校へ行け」と言ってくれた方が、どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか......**

The first sentence if for context, in the second:

- わざわざお母さんに、「教室移動の時間が長くなっている」と遠まわしに言わなくとも: Also without saying "The time for changing classrooms is getting longer" in a round about way to my mother (guessing 言わなくとも is the same as 言わなくても).
- ズバッと、わたしに向かって、「お前は東高じゃあ面倒みきれんで養護学校へ行け」と言ってくれた方が: turning towards me and saying to me "We can't take care of you at East High, so go to the school for disabled" would be more (the 方が part).
- どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか: I'm confused about this last part: [整理がつく](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F) in this case I think it's something like "To put order in one's feeling"; どんなにか I guess is どんなに + か, so "How much" plus the interrogative particle; all in all it sounds something like "How much should I put order in my feelings", but I don't really understand what should mean, and I don't understand how the 方が part fits in.

Context: the protagonist and her family are considering changing school from a normal one (East High) to one for disabled people; I'm guessing the speaker of the quoted parts is the teacher, since without passive お母さんに should be "[said] to my mother", with the first quote really said (「教室移動の時間が長くなっている」) and the second being just the protagonist wishing the teacher said that (「お前は東高じゃあ面倒みきれんで養護学校へ行け」).

Comment: @l'électeur I'm under the impression that the speaker could be N先生, which is saying to the mother that the time her daughter (which is disabled) needs to change classroom is increasing; or more in general someone else than the mother, but really while I think I understand pieces of that sentence, I could be missing it completely the general meaning.

Comment: I’m not sure where you got that “should” from in “How much **should** I …” It may be the か in どんなにか that is confusing you. Would you still have trouble understanding the phrase if it were どんなに気持ちの整理がつくか without the first か?

Comment: @aguijonazo yes, I don't really understand the meaning of that part (beside the guess I did), and I'm not sure how the 方が part from before fits in. The "should" derives from not really understanding that part: どんなに is "how", 気持ちの整理がつくか is (I think?) "put order in my feeling" + interrogative particle, and those two combined are like "how put order in my feelings", which in English sounds like a "should/could" sentence to me. But since I'm not really understanding that part I could be completely off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is confusing to you, but first the whole quote seems to be an inner speech of the protagonist, who apparently has some handicaps.

Second, when one says 気持ちの整理がつく, what is 'put in order' is the feelings themselves. The opposite is 気持ちが乱れる = to feel disturbed, annoyed, etc. So 気持ちの整理がつく means roughly *to calm down*, or in this context, to accept the situation (of being transferred to a school for disabled).

The whole quote describes the protagonist felt bad about the teacher N having made roundabout complaints to her(?) mother, instead of saying directly to her that she was becoming a burden. The last sentence means *the protagonist would feel much better if the teacher said so.* (*feel better* for the translation of 気持ちの整理がつく might be too liberal, but it is close to さっぱりする in this context, which means something like *get something off one's chest*)

---

Edit

In the second paragraph the following are compared

1. わざわざお母さんに、「教室移動の時間が長くなっている」と遠まわしに言わなくとも、
2. ズバッと、わたしに向かって、「お前は東高じゃあ面倒みきれんで養護学校へ行け」と言ってくれた方が

1 is what actually happened, and the protagonist wishes if 2 had happened instead (it didn't).

A fairly natural interpretation is the protagonist didn't like 1 because it made her feel that the teacher wasn't frank/honest with her in the sense that the teacher did feel the protagonist was a burden but did not tell her so. Then the protagonist wishes if the teacher frankly told her so, which would clear off her chest simply because it would mean the teacher was at least honest with her.

---

On 気持ちの整理がつく. It is more or less a set phrase, but a literal approach would be as follows.

First, in this context it is 私の気持ちの整理がつく (although the possessive would be usually omitted to avoid consecutive の), which is *my feelings is ordered*.

Second [a dictionary says](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86/#jn-122988)

> 乱れた状態にあるものを整えて、きちんとすること。「資料を整理する」「気持ちの整理がつく」「交通整理」

So 気持ちの整理がつく means "change from disturbed state to ordered state", which essentially means "to feel less disturbed, to calm down".

So どんなにか私の気持ちの整理がつくか is

- How more ordered my feelings will be

The condition to this "ordered feeling" is *if the teacher had told the protagonist, face to face, that she is becoming too burdensome to take care of in East high, so she should go to the school for disabled*.

---

Yet another approach is to consider の in 気持ちの整理がつく as the subject marker. どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか would be どんなにか**私は**気持ちの整理がつくか, which in turn becomes どんなにか 私は 気持ち**が**整理がつくか or どんなにか 私は 気持ち**が**整理**される**か, which is like

- How much more ordered the feelings will be for me

Of course, these expressions are totally unidiomatic, but possibly helpful in understanding the sentence.

Comment: The whole どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか is confusing to me, meaning I just can't really understand it: with 気持ちの整理がつくか meaning something like "to calm down", どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか sounds to me something like "how to calm down?". From what I understand of those words and grammar, I can't see how どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか means "the protagonist would feel much better" ("much" I guess derives from the 方が, but I'm confused about the rest).

Comment: You mean you can't make sense of the quote when 気持ちの整理がつく means _to calm down_ or you don't understand why 気持ちの整理がつく means _to calm down_?

Comment: I can sort of understand 気持ちの整理がつく as "to put order in one's feeling", meaning "to calm down" (not sure if that's why it has that meaning); but also taking it as a set phrase for "to calm down", I can't really understand what どんなにか気持ちの整理がつくか means.

Comment: I’m guessing the cause of the confusion could be 気持ちの整理がつくbeing a verb phrase. @Mauro might have little difficulty if that part were an adjective like 〜の方がどんなに（か）簡単か, for example.

Comment: @aguijonazo I would understand の方が簡単か (more easy), and I can understand の方がどんなに（か）簡単か if that means "how much easier", like これの方がどんなに（か）簡単か being "How much easier is this?".

Comment: Elaborated on both. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this right, she is saying that if the teacher had said something frankly to her she would have been kind of relieved? I'm saying "kind of" trying to express "how more ordered my feelings will be", which sounds like she thinks she would be more at ease, but she is not sure how much (which I'm under the impression is conveyed by the どんなにか part).

Comment: "どんなにか～か" is more simply "very much". Just like _How happy I am_ means _I'm very happy_, [どんなにうれしいことか](https://hyogen.info/content/477381605) means とてもうれしい. Here 気持ちの整理がつく works as something like an adjective to describe the state of mind (this is what @aguijonazo mentioned above). That is why I translated it as _feel much better_ in the first paragraph.

Comment: Besides that, I think your understanding is correct overall.